# RegExp for an identifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for an ID which comes in the following formats:

`7_b4718152-d9ed-4724-b3fe-e8dc9f12458a`

`b4718152-d9ed-4724-b3fe-e8dc9f12458a`

`[a_][b]-[c]-[d]-[e]-[f]`

- `a` - optional 0-3 digits followed by an underscore if there's at least
  a digit (if there is underscore is required)
- `b` - 8 alphanumeric characters
- `c` - 4 alphanumeric characters
- `d` - 4 alphanumeric characters
- `e` - 4 alphanumeric characters
- `f` - 12 alphanumeric characters

I have came up with this regexp but I would appreciate any guidance and/or corrections. I am also not too sure how to handle the optional underscore in the first segment if there are no digits up front.

`/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12})+/g`

Comment: Is "b" not 8 alnum chars? If so, try `^(?i)(?:\d{1,3}_)?[a-z\d]{8}(?:-[a-z\d]{4}){3}-[a-z\d]{12}$`

Comment: Yes, sorry, 8 characters; corrected.

Comment: What is the (?i) part? I haven't mentioned but I am writing this for a javascript function and I think it doesn't recognise that.

Comment: For JS use `/^(?:\d{1,3}_)?[a-z\d]{8}(?:-[a-z\d]{4}){3}-[a-z\d]{12}$/gi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks good. To optionally match the first 3 digits with an underscore, you can wrap that group with `()?`. Also you can force the presence of a digit before the underscore by using `{1,3}` instead of `{0,3}`.

Unless you expect that multiple identifiers are following each other without space and **should be matched as one**, you can drop the last `+` (for multiple matches on the same line, you already have the `g` option).

The final regex is `([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}_)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/dyQLAa/2) for a complete example.

If you also do not need to capture the individual 4-alphanumeric groups, you can simplify your regex into:

`([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}_)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/fDsbyO/1) for an example.